# Как сделать нумерацию записей при выборке sqlite3 + python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3

Допустим делаю запрос на выборку

```
sql.execute("SELECT nick, messages FROM users ORDER BY messages")
```

С этого запроса я получу список пользователей отсортированный по количеству сообщений в чате. Нужно присвоить каждому пользователю порядковый номер в этой выборке, как это можно сделать?

Comment: через `enumerate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i,line in enumerate(cur.execute("SELECT nick, messages FROM users ORDER BY messages")):
   print(i,*line)
```